# Okta Python SDK - how to obtain state token

Tags: python, okta

Hi I am trying to use the Okta Python SDK to change the password of a user. One of the required parameters is the state token. It isn't clear to me as to how I can get hold of a state token to begin with. I was unable to find any relevant examples in the available documentation. Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to change the password of a user, you can call the `change_password()` method using the `UsersClient`.

A `state_token` is only required when changing a user's password during the authentication flow.

```
from okta import UsersClient

usersClient = UsersClient("https://example.okta.com", "API_KEY")

changed_user = usersClient.change_password("USERNAME",
                                           "OLD_PASSWORD",
                                           "NEW_PASSWORD")
```

Comment: thanks @jmelberg. Looks like their documentation is not up to date with the SDK. I'm just going to rely on the SDK code to go through with the rest of my use cases.

Comment: @jmelberg is this still true? "A state_token is only required when changing a user's password during the authentication flow." In the okta postman authentication collection, all enroll factors require a state token. I'm not sure how to generate it- google led me here.